# Image directory location in Remote server

Tags: php

I am new to php.

I am using below code to upload image in local folder path "uploads/profilepics/".

```
move_uploaded_file
(
    $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 
    "uploads/profilepics/".$filenameWithUsername
);
```

It is working fine.

In remote server, my folder structure look like this, /public_html/myfamily/uploads/profilepics

I would like to know a good approach to store the image in remote server, if the code need some improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the __DIR__ magic constant (if youre lower than php 5.3 dirname(__FILE__)) to make sure your path is the same on local as on your server.

This will give you a fullpath to your dir no matter on what machine you are running.

So in your case id say try:

```
move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 
    __DIR__ . "/uploads/profilepics/".$filenameWithUsername
);
```

if it doesn't work

```
echo __DIR__ . "/uploads/profilepics/".$filenameWithUsername;
```

See what it shows and edit the path to where it needs to go if it isn't correct